# Can this batching problem be solved mathematically?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm a game programmer and I'm attempting to create the following function:

1. Two inputs: total amount ***ta*** and total duration ***td***.
2. Two outputs: batch amount ***ba*** and a set of batch durations [***bd***]  (total number of batches is unlimited).
3. The optimal batch duration is 50.
4. Amounts can be any decimal or whole number, but all durations are positive integers.

The function's goals are as follows:

1. SUM([***bd***]) = ***td*** (The sum of all batch durations is equal to the total duration).
2. ***ta*** = ***n(bd)*** * ***ba*** (total amount is equal to the batch amount times the total number of batches).
3. ***ba*** is as close as possible to an integer value.
4. [***bd***] values are as close as possible to 50 (less important than goal #3).

I'm unsure of how to handle the sum of a collection of variables.

**Context**

This is for a damage over time (DoT) batching function.  It takes the total damage (***ta***) and total duration (***td***) of the DoT and determines the batch amount (***ba***) (which is the amount of damage done per batch), the number of batches, and the duration of each batch [***bd***].

So in simple terms, the function needs to find an optimal set batch sizes that add up to the total duration and allows the batch amount to be as close as possible to a whole number.

A very simple ideal example of the function in action would be:

INPUT:

- ta = 100
- td = 200

OUTPUT:

- ba = 25
- [bd] = [50, 50, 50, 50]

But in practice, ***ta*** could be a decimal and ***td*** can be any  positive integer.

Comment: $a = bk$ for some integer $k$ but then you can see that $b = \frac ak$ which means that if $a$ is not an integer then there is no $b$ as close as possible to a whole number because $b$ goes to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity

Comment: I see - looks like I made a logic error there.  So assuming we remove requirement #4 and allow ourselves to adjust **a** and **d** such that the product of **a** and **d** remains constant (batch overflow); is there a solution then?

Comment: What is the difference between the batched amount and the batch size? Please provide a basic numeric example (doesn't have to be optimal).

Comment: I realized that I was over-constraining the problem and that each batch can be a different size.  I've edited my question to fix these mistakes and added some context regarding what each value does.